# ImportError: cannot import name .... in python

Tags: python

I have class as the following:

```
import skimage.io as io
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import glob, re, os

class convertImages:

    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory

    def renameImages(self):
        path = self.directory
        i = 1
        files = [s for s in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, s))]
        files.sort(key = lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, s)))

        for file in files:
            os.rename(path + file, path + str(i) + '.png')
            i = i + 1
```

I want to call this class from my Main:

```
import convertImages
from convertImages import renameImages

ci = convertImages('Pictures/trialRGB')
```

But get this damn error: `ImportError: cannot import name renameImages`

I don't know what is the stupid logic behind this. I have done everything according to tutorial. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: _"I have done everything according to tutorial"_. Which tutorial?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: What happens if you just delete `from convertImages import renameImages`? You don't seem to be using that method anyway.

Comment: I have to call the damn method renameImages

Comment: `renameImages` is a method of `convertImages` class. Hence, you get the error. Why did you put such import in your file?

Comment: If you're calling `renameImages` somewhere, please include that in the code you're showing us.

Comment: @yusuf so call it `ci.renameImages()`

Comment: How will I call the parameter in this case, Kevin?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you have a module and a class with the same name here.

Comment: No, I don't, shuttle87.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't import the `renameImages` method that is part of the `convertImages` class. And based on your code, you don't need to.

Just delete the `from convertImages import renameImages` line, and your code should run without any problems.

If you need to use the `renameImages` method, you use it as part of the instance you use -- just call it like so:

```
ci.renameImages()
```

You need to run that method as part of an instance -- otherwise, it won't work.

UPDATE (from comments): You also need to change `import convertImages` to `from convertImages import convertImages`.

Comment: It didn't work without problems. Here is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hasan/Documents/Project/Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    ci = convertImages('Pictures/trialRGB')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: You're right, I missed that. You need to change the first line to `from convertImages import convertImages`. The first `convertImages` is your module, and the second is the class declaration in your module.

Comment: But how will I send the parameter to the class in this case?

Comment: You don't need to change the code instantiating the class -- you just need to change the import statement. BTW, I haven't looked closely at your code itself, so that might also break.

Comment: Did you remove the import convertImages line?  Since your module and class have the same name, those import statements will conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83875/discussion-between-tobylaroni-and-yusuf).